# Rigging, can not rotate the bones. Rigify Pitchipoy

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, bones, rigify

After I generate the bones using Rigify pitchipoy none of the rotation commands work.

[image: Rig before generating]

[image: controls like the highlighted one wont work.]

[image: Ik controls do seem to be working though I can not rotate the wrist to match the position.]

Rig before generating
Controls like the highlighted one wont rotate
The IK controls of the hands and feet do seem to work, but I cant move the wrist to match the rest of it.

I tried to show you everything you need to see in the pictures I'm not sure what else you might need to see. Please let me know. Thank you for your time :D!

EDIT!!!
I found a new bit of weird. I turned on "Auto IK" which fixed some of the issues but the arms are still funky [image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It is possible that for some reason or another, when you generated controls, a limit rotation constraint was placed on the bones.  If this is the case, when you go to pose mode, select a bone that won't rotate, and look at the bone constraints panel, you might see something like this.

Comment: I didn't find anything like that

Comment: I turned on "Auto IK" that fixed the waiste but not the wrist. I've also added an image to show what happens when I rotate the arms now.

Answer (score 1):

In pose mode, select a bone you want to rotate, check your transform tab (N key), is the rotation locked?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have all the layers enabled here which is not quite as desired.

Hide all the layers. After that, use the buttons to enable Arm IK Left and Arm IK Right. Make sure the IK / FK slider is set to IK. If you are not sure which is which, try both. Maybe that will solve your problem. The slider is located in your viewport in screenshot #1 and #2 on the right panel.

Ensure Auto-IK is **disabled**

On the bone properties panel, ensure the rotation on XYZW is not "Locked".

I feel like the IK / FK slider is your issue. It's the reason why your mesh does not deform when you move the IK part of the Armature. It could also be the cause for it's inability to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your screenshots, you have "manipulate center points" turned on. It would cause the problems you described. See Screenshot.
[image: manipulate center points button]

Comment: Please do not write in the images. A simple mark around the button would be sufficient.

Comment: No problem. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this thread is old and I'm using a newer version of Blender (2.91) I'm going to answer this question, because I just finally discovered the answer myself after searching for posts like this and never quite finding the right solution. This will probably mainly be of use to people suffering this issue now.

After rigging my character using Rigify, I discovered that I could only translate the IK controllers in the main window, not rotate or scale them. I could hit N and enter values directly into the rotation and scale fields, but not adjust interactively.

Eventually I noticed that when I was in Pose Mode the popup in the upper right of the main window changed to "Pose Options" If you click on this, and then uncheck "Affect Only - Locations" the rotate and scale commands will now work as expected in the viewport.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to this. This solved the issue for me.